# The object empty check is not working and changing the logic

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I am doing a form validation check and I have taken 'formErrors' and set the errors in this object. However it is initially {} and in my code I am checking for Object.keys(formErrors).length===0 which returns true for even {}

```
  const [formValues, setFormValues] = useState(initialValues);
  const [formErrors, setFormErrors] = useState({});

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setFormValues({ ...formValues, [name]: value });
  };

  const url = '/collectdetails';

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setFormErrors(validate(formValues));
    // setIsSubmit(true);
    console.log(noErrors);
    if (noErrors) {
      const { fullName, phoneNumber, emailAddress, role, lookingFor, company } =
        formValues;
      const data = {
        Name: fullName,
        MobileNumber: phoneNumber,
        Email: emailAddress,
        Role: role,
        LookingFor: lookingFor,
        CompanyName: company,
      };

      getDetails(url, data).then((user) => {
        const { Response } = user;

        if (Response === 'OK') {
          setCurrentUser(phoneNumber);
          navigate('/');
        }
      });
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (Object.keys(formErrors).length === 0) {
      console.log(formErrors);
      setNoErrors(true);
    }
  }, [formErrors]);
```

So When I submit the handleSubmit() method is run and it has 2 nested checks. The first one is for noErrors which is a bool state that checks if my object is empty. I have console logged it and it returns true when the component loads as the object is {} in the beginning. Is there any way for me to put a check so that I can see if there are some keys present in the object?

Comment: you just need to use `setNoErrors(false)` in validate function if there is error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`useEffect` will run every time your `formErrors` object changes. This includes the first render.

It would probably be better for you to put your `useEffect` logic inside your submit handler. The formErrors state object just seems to function as a temporary store for you as you immediately call `setNoErrors(true)` if it is populated:

```
const [formValues, setFormValues] = useState(initialValues);

const handleChange = (e) => {
  const { name, value } = e.target;
  setFormValues({ ...formValues, [name]: value });
};

const url = '/collectdetails';

const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    // just store in a normal variable
    const errors = validate(formValues);

    // setIsSubmit(true);
    console.log(noErrors); // this isn't defined in your code

    // just check the errors object for keys
    if (Object.keys(errors).length === 0) {
      // errors object is empty
      console.log(errors);
      setNoErrors(true);
      const { fullName, phoneNumber, emailAddress, role, lookingFor, company }
        = formValues;
      const data = {
        Name: fullName,
        MobileNumber: phoneNumber,
        Email: emailAddress,
        Role: role,
        LookingFor: lookingFor,
        CompanyName: company,
      };

      getDetails(url, data).then((user) => {
      const { Response } = user;

      if (Response === 'OK') {
        setCurrentUser(phoneNumber);
        navigate('/');
      }
    });
  }
};
```